# Assumptions on Neural Networks (NNETAR)

Tags: neural-networks, forecasting, assumptions, autoregressive

Are there any assumptions that must be covered when fitting an NNETAR model? non-correlation, normality, or something? I've already saw Rob Hyndman post where he says NNETAR doesn´t need stationarity, but how about the other usual assumptions?

Comment: A useful assumption is that the data generating process is the same out of sample as it is in sample. This could be understood as a form of stationarity. (I presume the context is forecasting, so I added the tag.)

Comment: Thanks Richard, and yes, it's for forecasting an hourly time series. Problem is, even using 6 lags, 2 seasonal lags, and some regressors, residuals are still correlated (I don´t want to make a more complex model because there´re many observations and it would take more than 30mins to estimate). Forecast looks good and RMSE is pretty nice, so I don´t know if the model is statistically significant or not.

Comment: A neural network is not a model that would produce interesting parameter estimates, but it may produce good forecasts. Hence, I would not talk of statistical significance of the model. But you could compare the forecast accuracy to a benchmark by a Diebold-Mariano test to assess the probability that the forecasts beat the benchmark only due to chance. If the probability is low, you could be happy with your model. Also, if the effect size (the average difference between losses from the neural network and the benchmark) is "large" (which is subjective), you should also be satisfied.